# I am trying to get a month and year to date column in SQL

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am trying to create a month and year to date column but the FY starts from October and I need it to roll into the next year so this can automatically update in Power Bi I have the Date ID for our year now maybe need flags to show the current month and current year then I can create a measure in Power Bi, also need it to sum up the months for year to date etc if I click january it shows me sales from October to January.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate fiscal year in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771995/calculate-fiscal-year-in-sql-server)

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771995/9606612, specifically this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1772026/9606612

Comment: This is not a code writing community. First try out and post the error!!!